# Still not understanding .this after reading articles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm a JS/React beginner who has read a few articles on the this keyword on JS, but remain confused.
Namely, I've consulted Tyler McGinnis's React and The Complete Javascript on Udemy.

This keyword is a fairly complex topic imo, but from these two sources I know .this refers to the global scope by default, but refers to the object in question when it is defined within a method. I also know that .call/apply/bind can give us a hint on what the .this refers to.

My question is, when do you actually write the .this keyword when you are writing your programs? The sources above seemed to focus on understanding why others might've used the keyword, but not necessarily when you need to do it. Thus, I always get confused when tutorials seemingly randomly throw in a this/bind etc everywhere

In terms of specific examples, I have :
1. One in the context of states:
[image]

2. I've encountered apps before learning about the .this concept which do not use the .this keyword. No specific examples for this, but shouldn't you use .this most of the time then?

Apologies if this is a silly question -- sometimes I wonder whether it is better to analyze/dissect the rationale for each part in coding or just to learn coding as just the way things are much like a child learns a language naturally without questioning grammar rules

3. In this example, we are passing down a prop called onDelete, but I do not understand why we need to bind. Does this mean we are binding the passed down onDelete to props.id which was also passed down?
   [image]

Comment: Using the classes yes.  It provides a context for property variables that belong to this component.  For pure functions they are generally passed as parameters and scoped variables.

Comment: _"sometimes I wonder whether it is better to analyze/dissect the rationale for each part in coding or just to learn coding as just the way things are much like a child learns a language naturally without questioning grammar rules"_ -> Everyone learns differently, but IMO you need a bit of both. It's good to try to udnerstand the "theory", but don't get get lost for too long trying to wrap your head around a concept that is not clear, precisely because you don't have enough experience to get the idea and the big picture. And after a while, go back on the foundations, it will be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The important part is you took the time to research. Personally I do not recommend using React to learn about `this`. When you extend a React component, your `this` prototype inherits from React.Component, so there's a lot of React-specific conventions there already. Instead, consider this example where I call `this` directly

```js
function SimpleQueue({ size }) {
  this.size = size
  this.buffer = []
}

SimpleQueue.prototype.push = function(item) {
  this.buffer.push(item)
  if (this.buffer.length > this.size) {
    this.buffer.shift()
  }
  return this
}
```

`SimpleQueue` is just a simple queue implementation using an internal array. You can think of `this` as a reference to the current instance of `SimpleQueue`, whatever that may be. I use `this` specifically in the example above to access the internal array as `this.buffer`. I can then use an instance of a `SimpleQueue` like so

```js
const mySimpleQueue = new SimpleQueue({ size: 3 })
mySimpleQueue.push(1) // SimpleQueue { 1 }
mySimpleQueue.push(2) // SimpleQueue { 1, 2 }
mySimpleQueue.push(3) // SimpleQueue { 1, 2, 3 }
mySimpleQueue.push(4) // SimpleQueue { 2, 3, 4 }
```

Note: my example does not use `class`, but it is the same because [classes are syntactic sugar for the prototype-based programming model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes)

Answer (score 0):

"this" is not a complex topic. people make it complex.

you have

```
handleTitleChange=(title)=>{
this.setState({})
}
```

When you say `this.setState()` you want `this` to refer the class component that you defined the handleTitleChange() inside. Arrow functions AUTOMATICALLY allow you to set “this” when the function is defined. That is why it is said that arrow functions are lexically bound to this. When our component is getting rendered by javascript for the first time, it checks inside and sees that there is `handleTitleChange()` points to arrow function. The moment it sees “this”, it is going to automatically bind “this” to the place where the arrow function is defined in the the first place. The context of that function is the TimerForm component.

But by default javascript does not set its scope of “this” on functions. "this" is dynamically scoped, it does not matter where the function is written, it matters how the function is called. That is why we have to actually explicitly state what context you want “this” to be for us. We want “this” to be our class component and the method in which we can do it is to define in our `constructor()`.  If you write above code like this :

```
handleTitleChange(title){
    this.setState({})
    }
```

Now,in the above function `this` refers to the class but when you pass the reference to be called by another component or function, you are not passing its "this" anymore. New "this" will be assigned by object which calls "handleTitleChange(title)". We have to make sure that when we call `handleTitleChange(title)`, its "this" value always points to `TimerForm` class. So we go to `constructor(){}`. Because our `constructor()` is the code that runs first before anything gets called. We want to make sure that the context of `this` is correct in all of our methods before any code gets written.

```
constructor(){
super()
console.log(this) // it will log TimerForm class 
this.handleTitleChange=this.handleTitleChange.bind(this)

//bind(this) `this` refers to the TimerForm
}
```

bind() is a method on any function that returns a new function with a new execution context. now our `handleTitleChange` method learnt that `this` inside of it, will refer to the TimerForm class component.

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't you use `.this` most of the time then?

Yes, for class based react components, you should almost everywhere use `this.`, for access props, state, handlers, calling methods etc.

`constructor` is an exception ... `this.state` is created, `props` are constructor argument.

Handlers declared using `handleChange(e) {}` syntax needs `.bind(this)` to be able:

- to operate on `this.state`;
- to use `this.setState()` (react component method derived from base class);
- to use other methods defined in this component.

**Usually event handlers are binded in constructor** in the form like:

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

<button onClick={this.handleClick} />
```

Event handlers defined using ES6 'arrow syntax' `fn = () => {}` are autobinded to `this`.

Also handlers defined using 'normal function syntax' but assigned using 'arrow syntax' in `render` doesn't need binding:

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} />
```

**Bad news** - every render call crates new ref ... at least not optimal in react ... so ... **use arrow declaration** (or `bind` in constructor).

> we are passing down a prop called onDelete, but I do not understand why we need to bind

Why? Probably passed handler not binded - rare requirement to bind handler to different object/component context (different `this`).

Answer (score 0):

to your 3rd question. `props.onDelete` is a function that's passed down, it's binding on `this`, which is the current execution context in `<TouchableOpacity>`, `props.id` is the argument of the onDelete function.
this is the old way, I believe an arrow function will do the same thing, `() => props.onDelete(props.id)`

And in react world/javascript land, function components/object destructing/arrow function are taking more ground these days, might be a reason you see less/none `this` in the codebase.